# C++: What is faster - lookup in hashmap or switch statement?

Tags: c++, performance, hashmap, switch-statement

I have a code pattern which translates one integer to another. Just like this:

```
int t(int value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1: return const_1;
        case 3: return const_2;
        case 4: return const_3;
        case 8: return const_4;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

It has about 50 entries currently, maybe later on there will be some more, but probably no more than hundred or two. All the values are predefined, and of course I can order case labels by their values. So the question is, what will be faster - this approach or put this into hash map (I have no access to std::map, so I'm speaking about custom hash map available in my SDK) and perform lookups in that table? Maybe it's a bit of premature optimization, though... But I just need your opinions.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: My case values are going to be in range from 0 to 0xffff. And regarding the point of better readability of hash map. I'm not sure it really will have better readability, because I still need to populate it with values, so that sheet of constants mapping is still needs to be somewhere in my code.

**EDIT-2**: Many useful answers were already given, much thanks. I'd like to add some info here. My hash key is integer, and my hash function for integer is basically just one multiplication with integral overflow:

```
EXPORT_C __NAKED__ unsigned int DefaultHash::Integer(const int& /*aInt*/)
{
_asm mov edx, [esp+4]
_asm mov eax, 9E3779B9h
_asm mul dword ptr [edx]
_asm ret
}
```

So it should be quite fast.

Comment: you shouldn't really return from a void, and yes it is premature optimization, but I personally would go for good hash map (for the reasons of redability)

Comment: (1) `std::map` isn't a hashmap (`std::unordered_map` from C++11 is). (2) How are we supposed to judge the quality of that custom hash map? It may be utter garbage or be excellent.

Comment: As an aside, maybe consider an `enum` with named pairs instead of a `switch`? That would get rid of the function call completely.

Comment: @Haspemulator and what about default?

Comment: @delnan: yes, I understand you cannot judge the quality of custom map. But let's presume that it is a _good_ hash map.

Comment: @smallB: thanks again, I'm just typing faster than thinking...

Comment: Why not using a simple array as a conversion table ? Are your integers going to be very large ?

Comment: @Haspemulator you may consider using instead of '0' simply constant like for example UNKNOWN_VALUE, I believe it is better for code clarity (magic constants aren't really popular anymore)

Comment: You may like this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/switch.aspx

Comment: "I just need your opinions" - no you don't. Our opinions which is faster are pretty much worthless since we don't have your hashmap implementation, your compiler, your actual data, or the rest of your application. All of those can have an effect on which is faster (and whether the difference is noticeable), so all anyone can really say is that they're probably both fast but normally the switch would be faster.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: yes, I understand your point. But it could be that somebody say that, for example, switch is definitely faster in the given conditions (number and nature of cases values, presuming proper hash map implementation, etc.). I.e. without doubts. But peoples' answer are stating that the exact answer is unobvious, and that is also important fact for me.

Comment: Use an array.  See my answer below.

Comment: Use a binary tree (such as std::map) its faster than both for about 50 entries.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `switch` construct is faster (or at least not slower).

That's mostly because a `switch` construct gives static data to the compiler, while a runtime structure like a hash map doesn't.

When possible compilers should compile `switch` constructs into array of code pointers: each item of the array (indexed by your indexes) points to the associated code. At runtime this takes O(1), while a hash map could take more: O(log n) at average case or O(n) at worst case, usually, and anyway a bigger constant number of memory accesses.

Comment: hash map in O(n) is a pretty bad hash map

Comment: Did I get something wrong in my education I thought hashing should be `O(1)` and in worst case (many collisions) `O(N)`? Also I would say the speed of the switch depends on the values you want to tell apart. If they are a closed range with fixed step size switches are fast. But what about a range like [1,100000000] with random entries?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, fixed it. O(n) is the worst case (or it could be always O(log n) for tree maps). My point anyway was supposed to be: it could take more than O(1) in some conditions, and even when it's O(1) it will most probably requires a bigger number of constant operations.

Comment: @Nobody: `switch` are implemented as an array when possible, in your example it's not, but since that data is statically available to the compiler, it should be able to give a result non worse than whatever runtime structure.

Comment: Don't switch statements use binary searches, which would be O(log(n)) complexity, as opposed to O(1) for a hashmap? Obviously, there's the overhead of the hash function too, but for pure time complexity, this seems off.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: no binary search is needed when switch indices are contiguous. When the indices are non-contiguous the compiler could generate a statically-optimized hashmap (which would still be non-worse than a dynamically constructed hashmap). - In general the compiler and your running program would have a similar amount of information, but the switch statement will be able to process this information at compile time and optimize using some heuristics that are most likely way better than anything we could ever achieve at runtime.

Comment: @peoro If the data is contiguous though, you could always use a static array as well: if the data is non-contiguous, although you're unlikely to notice major differences, at very large sizes `O(1)` with a decent large coefficient starts to beat `O(log(n))` with a small coefficient. You're mostly right, but the example above is clearly not contiguous.

Comment: Look into amortization.

Answer (score 10):

I will add my 5 cents:

For the number of entries at about 50 std::unordered_map (hash based, O(1)) is typically slower then std::map (tree based O(ln(N))), and both of them are slower then boost::flat_map(sorted vector O(ln(N))) which I tend to use in such cases.
It is not always the case that switch can be compiled to jump table, and when it is, you can simply put your values (or functions) in vector yourself and access by index. Otherwise switch is marginally faster than boost::flat_map.

Please note the word "typically" in the beginning, if you do care about performance of this piece of code do the profiling (and share results with us :)).

Comment: As always, to find great answer, look at the bottom most replies.

Answer (score 5):

A `switch statement` is going to be quicker than a look up in a hash map.

However, a map is going to result in much more readable code if you ever change the mappings. You can easily do this with a map by reading the results in from a file.  In a switch statement you'd have to change the code and recompile.

Answer (score 3):

The switch will be faster. If it's a small number of cases, as in your example, it will use an if-chain. If a large number of cases, and if they are reasonably compact, it has the option to generate a jump-table, which only takes a few instructions. (BTW you don't have to order the cases.) The hash-map is O(1), but will probably take in the range of 10-40 instructions.

Comment: Regarding the ordering of cases: I read somewhere that I should do it to achieve higher execution speed. So you say it's wrong? Can you give some more details on this?

Comment: @Hasp - **If** the code turns into an if-chain, the first case could be *ever so slightly* faster. If the compiler decides on a jump table, it doesn't help.

Comment: @Haspemulator: Bo's basically right. You could have a lot of sparse cases (like 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, etc.), causing the compiler to make a long if-chain. Then in the worst case, your program might have to always run down to the very last one.

Answer (score 3):

An array will have the fastest access time, by definition.

The switch statement compares values, then uses a jump table (which is an array of function pointers).

The *hashmap* computes a hash value from the data, then either searches a tree in memory or uses the hash value as an index into an array.  Slow because of computing the hash value.

On most modern platforms, 64k, is not a big amount of data and can be statically allocated as a constant array.

One problem with the array technique is account for keys that you have not accounted for.  One example is to use a unique sentinel value.  When the value is returned, you know you have an unknown key.

I suggest using a `static const` array of values.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of a hash map will depend on two things: the speed of the hash function, and the number of collisions. When all of the values are known ahead of time, it's possible to create a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash) that has no collisions. If you can generate a perfect hash function that only consists of a couple of arithmetic operations, it will potentially be faster than the switch.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with using an array, but I don't have the reputation to vote for it.  It's only 65536 entries, so unless you're under serious memory constraints and/or you're returning something very large, instead of int like your example, you will be much better off with a static const array.  Having an array of 64k int's is generally only 256kB, and it would be half or 1/4 that size if you can use a short or char.  I think the best you can hope for with a switch statement is a conditional branch for values outside of it's array of code pointers and a second conditional branch to jump to the code for a value inside the array.  Being able to just execute "return my_array[value]" will just result in a memory fetch (possibly from l3 cache).

For readability, you can stick the array in its own file and line up all the values in a grid with something like 10 or 16 entries per line.  Then you comment each line with the first part of each entry number (e.g. "// 0x12A?" ), and have periodic comment lines that would line up with the columns to fill in the last digit for the entry number (e.g. "//  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F").  I've done this for several arrays of 256 entries, which has been much easier to manage than a switch statement.  I've also used arrays with 64k entries for fast integer logarithms, which get more complicated to manage, but I was able to write a program to generate all the array code.

With something that large, code management may not be easier until you're dealing with more entries, but it depends on your editor and skill with it.  Maintaining such an array is just adjusting a spot in a chart instead of hunting down values that may or may not be in a long list of "case 1: return const_1;".  A couple of for loops should suffice to generate an array of 64k entries, that are properly commented and filled with default values.

For access safety, you might consider using some sort of bounds checking.  This could be done with boost's preconditions, throwing an exception or special return if the number is out of bounds, or a simple "return my_array[value&0xffff]".  However, you might have a strong enough guarantee on your incoming value that you don't need any of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not obvious which is going to be faster. You might need to profile both approaches.

The hash map should have complexity of O(1).

The switch (with non-contiguous keys like yours) may be optimized into a binary search (at least with GCC), which has complexity of O(log n).

On the other hand, any operation done on a hash map will be much more expensive than an operation done in a switch.

Answer (score 1):

Hash table time complexity is generally O(1) when don't considering collision.
C++ standard doesn't specified how switch is implemented but it can be implemented as jump-table which time complexity is O(1) too or it can be implemented as binary search which time complexity is O(log n) or a combination depending on how many case statement etc.

So in a word, small scale like your case, switch is faster, but hash table might win in large scale